# Javascript: Image does not get updated immediately

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to learn Javascript from the book Head First Javascript (Morrison).

Inside the function findSeat(), the code is supposed to update the image to 'seat_select.png' for every seat that is available and then ask for a confirmation.

However, when I run the code, the images are updated immediately (as expected) only sometimes. Otherwise, the images are updated only after the loop has completed.

Why is this happening?

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Movie Ticket Finder</title>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var seats = [ false, true, false, true, true, true, false, true, false ];
        var selSeat = -1;

        function initSeats() {
            // Initialize the appearance of all seats
            for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
                if (seats[i]) {
                    // Set the seat to available
                    document.getElementById("seat" + i).src = "seat_avail.png";
                    document.getElementById("seat" + i).alt = "Available seat";
                }
                else {
                    // Set the seat to unavailable
                    document.getElementById("seat" + i).src = "seat_unavail.png";
                    document.getElementById("seat" + i).alt = "Unavailable seat";
                }
            }
        }

        function findSeat() {
            // If seat is already selected, reinitialize all seats to clear them
            if (selSeat >= 0) {
                selSeat = -1;
                initSeats();
            }

            // Search through all the seats for availability
            for (var i = 0; i < seats.length; i++) {
                // See if the current seat is available
                if (seats[i]) {
                    // Set the seat selection and update the appearance of the seat
                    selSeat = i;
                    document.getElementById("seat" + i).src = "seat_select.png";
                    document.getElementById("seat" + i).alt = "Your seat";

                    // Prompt the user to accept the seat
                    var accept = confirm("Seat " + (i + 1) + " is available. Accept?");
                    if (!accept) {
                        // The user rejected the seat, so clear the seat selection and keep looking
                        selSeat = -1;
                        document.getElementById("seat" + i).src = "seat_avail.png";
                        document.getElementById("seat" + i).alt = "Available seat";
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>

<body onload="initSeats();">
    <div style="margin-top:75px; text-align:center">
        <img id="seat0" src="" alt="" />
        <img id="seat1" src="" alt="" />
        <img id="seat2" src="" alt="" />
        <img id="seat3" src="" alt="" />
        <img id="seat4" src="" alt="" />
        <img id="seat5" src="" alt="" />
        <img id="seat6" src="" alt="" />
        <img id="seat7" src="" alt="" />
        <img id="seat8" src="" alt="" /><br />
        <input type="button" id="findseat" value="Find Seat" onclick="findSeat();" />
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT: Based on Oleg Yudovich's answer, this is what I added to my code. Now everything works as expected!

```
  <div style="display: none">
      <img id="seat_unavail" src="seat_unavail.png" alt="" />
      <img id="seat_avail" src="seat_avail.png" alt="" />
      <img id="seat_select" src="seat_select.png" alt="" />
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you include new image in your html, your browser is download this image and put it to cache, before displaying.This process is take time. If your images is big size, is take more time. So you can solve your problem by caching images before your loop is start running :

```
 <div style="display:none;">
     <img id="seat0" src="some image source" alt=""/>
     <img id="seat0" src="some image source" alt=""/>
     <img id="seat0" src="some image source" alt=""/>
     <img id="seat0" src="some image source" alt=""/>
     <img id="seat0" src="some image source" alt=""/>
     <img id="seat0" src="some image source" alt=""/>
 </div>
```

This hidden block,if you put him on your site start page, will load all images into browser cache.